# Problema para achar números primos

Tags: c

Hoje na faculdade aprendi sobre o `for` e o `while`. Entretanto, o código que estou tentando formular não roda. Ele compila mas "buga" depois que põe o valor. O código é simplesmente pra verificação se o número é primo ou não.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int a,b,i;
        printf("Entre com o numero para saber se e primo");
        scanf ("%d", &a);
        i=a;
        while (i>1){
            b=a/(i-1);
            i=i-1;
                if (a%(i-1)==0){
                     printf ("Nao Primo");
                }else
                     printf ("Primo");
        }
        system ("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

O problema é que como você diminui o valor de `i`, uma hora ele valerá 1 e você estará dividindo `a` por 0:

```
b = a / (1-1);
```

Simplificando sua lógica, você poderia criar uma função que verificasse se um número é primo ou não de uma maneira mais direta:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool TestePrimo(int a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < a; i++) 
    {
        if (a % i == 0 && i != a) //Se o número é divisível por outro número que não seja ele mesmo, ele não é primo.
            return false;
    }

    return true; //Se nenhum teste do laço retornou valor, então o número é primo.
}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("Entre com o numero para saber se e primo");
    scanf ("%d", &a);

    if (TestePrimo(a))
       printf("Primo");
    else
       printf("Nao primo");

    system ("pause");
}
```

Aproveitando os apontamentos do mgibsonbr, o uso do `break` seria interessante para manter a checagem dentro da função `main`:

```
int i;
bool verifica = true; //Variável booleana que indicará se o número é primo (true) ou não (false).
for (i = 2; i < a; i++) 
{
    if (a % i == 0 && i != a)
    {
        verifica = false;
        break; //Sair do laço pois um divisor do número já foi encontrado, comprovando que ele não é primo.
    }
}

if(verifica == false)
   printf("Nao primo");
else
   printf("Primo");
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos ver o que acontece com um exemplo

```
                                      // a b i
scanf("%d", &a);                      // 3
i = a;                                // 3   3
while (i > 1){                        // OK
    b = a / (i - 1);                  // 3 1 3
    i = i - 1;                        // 3 1 2
    if (a % (i - 1) == 0){            // o resto da divisao de 3 por 1 = 0
        printf("Nao primo");          // OOPS
while (i > 1){                        // OK
    b = a / (i - 1);                  // 3 1 3
    i = i - 1;                        // 3 1 1
    if (a % (i - 1) == 0){            // o resto da divisao de 3 por 0 da erro
```

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema, como as demais respostas apontaram, é que você está subtraindo `1` de `i` e **depois** fazendo uma operação envolvendo `i - 1`. A maneira mais direta de resolver é movendo o decremento de `i` para o final:

```
    while (i>1){
        b=a/(i-1);
        //i=i-1;                    // <-- Sai daqui...
        if (a%(i-1)==0){
             printf ("Nao Primo");
        }else
             printf ("Primo");
        i=i-1;                      // <-- ...e vem pra cá.
    }
```

Eu também sugeriria parar no `2` em vez do `1`, pois caso contrário você eventualmente fará `a % 1` que é sempre `0` (ou seja, o programa dirá que todo número é "Nao primo").

Além disso, há duas outras coisas "estranhas" no seu código:

1. A cada teste o programa vai imprimir `"Primo"` ou `"Nao Primo"`. Se você testar com `6` por exemplo a saída será:

   ```
   Primo
   Primo
   Nao primo
   Nao primo
   Primo
   ```

   Em vez disso, coloque numa variável se o número é primo ou não, e só imprima o resultado no final do teste:

   ```
   int primo = 1; // Na falta de informação em contrário, todo número é primo
   i=a;
   while (i>2){
       b=a/(i-1);
       if (a%(i-1)==0){
            primo = 0; // Agora sabemos com certeza que não é primo
       }
       // Não precisa do else, se não achamos um divisor ele continua como está
       i=i-1;
   }
   if (primo == 0){
        printf ("Nao Primo");
   }else
        printf ("Primo");
   ```
2. A variável `b` nunca é utilizada, então pra que você precisa dela? Ela pode ser removida.

Fora isso, há o uso do `break` - que talvez você ainda não tenha aprendido. Spoiler: ele serve pra parar um loop mais cedo. Se dentro do `if` você colocar uma instrução adicional - `break;` - então agora que ele sabe com certeza que o número não é primo ele não precisa continuar testando, ele para por aí mesmo. Há também um meio de parar mais cedo sem o uso do `break`:

```
while (i>2 && primo != 0){
```

Ou seja, só continue se o `i` for maior que `2` **E** o número não for comprovadamente não-primo.

Comment: Nota: eu aprendi C um milhão de anos atrás, na época que nem `bool` tinha, então dei minha resposta usando `0` pra representar "falso" e `1` pra representar "verdadeiro". Como não sei o que **você** sabe (já que ainda está aprendendo) preferi deixar o exemplo mais simples - introduzindo o mínimo de conceitos novos.

Answer (score 0):

Uma recomendação adicional que posso dar é para melhorar a performance do algoritmo:

Ao procurar por um número primo **N** o número máximo da iteração (no seu caso a variável i) deverá ser **N**/2. Um exemplo seria testar se o número 7 é primo. Só faz sentido testar se o 7 é divisível por 2, 3 e 4. Todo número que for maior que a metade de 7 nunca conseguira dividi-lo sem ter um resto de divisão. Neste caso os números 5 e 6 sempre darão um resto de divisão.

Um outro exemplo, quero saber se 11 é primo ou não:
Vou testar se 11 é divisível por 2, 3, 4, 5 e 6; Qualquer número acima disso não é necessário testar, pois sempre terá resto de divisão maior que 1;